# Installing Perl modules and dependencies with non-root and without CPAN

Tags: perl, module

I have been writing Perl scripts for my work and the machine that I have been given to work on makes installing Perl modules difficult:

- We cannot have `gcc` on my machine for security reasons, so I cannot use CPAN to install modules, for most modules.
- I do not have access to the root account.

Usually, when I want to install a module, I put in a request and I have to wait a day or two before it gets installed. I know that nobody would have a problem with me installing them myself, so to save everyone's time and my sanity I would like to install them myself.  It's just an issue of how to best do that.  I have talked to various people and they said to use an RPM to install them (to get around not having `gcc`).  However, when trying to install modules from RPMs, it does not handle the dependencies so I would manually need to handle the dependencies, which could take a while.

How can I best install Perl modules with these limitations?

Comment: Tool/implementation questions are usually a better fit on SO. Please don't re-ask this there as this can get migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If you question has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers.

Comment: What possible security issue can gcc cause that a perl interpreter can't?

Comment: Programmer with no access to compiler...what is this world coming to?

Comment: @Walter Thanks for the heads up, I'll remember that in the future.

Comment: Most modules are pure Perl, which means you don't actually need gcc.

Answer (score 3):

On a similar machine with a similarly built Perl, install the module(s) using

```
mkdir ~/foo
cpan
o conf makepl_arg 'PREFIX=~/foo LIB=~/foo/lib/perl5'
o conf mbuildpl_arg '--prefix ~/foo --lib ~/foo/lib/perl5'
install Some::Module
```

As long as you don't do `o conf commit`, the configuration change will be temporary, so don't do that.

Copy `~/foo` over, and set env var `PERL5LIB` to include the LIB directory. You can merge a newer `~/foo` into an older one to add new modules.

This won't install any non-Perl libraries on which the modules depend.

Answer (score 0):

See also [How do I keep my own module/library directory?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-keep-my-own-module%2flibrary-directory%3f) in section 8 of the Perl FAQ.

> When you build modules, tell Perl where to install the modules.
>
> For `Makefile.PL`-based distributions, use the `INSTALL_BASE` option when generating `Makefile`s:
>
> ```
> perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/mydir/perl
> ```
>
> For `Build.PL`-based distributions, use the `--install_base` option:
>
> ```
> perl Build.PL --install_base /mydir/perl
> ```
>
> `INSTALL_BASE` tells these tools to put your modules into `/mydir/perl/lib/perl5`. See [How do I add a directory to my include path (`@INC`) at runtime?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-add-a-directory-to-my-include-path-(%40INC)-at-runtime%3f) for details on how to run your newly installed modules.
>
> There is one caveat with `INSTALL_BASE`, though, since it acts differently from the `PREFIX` and `LIB` settings that older versions of `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` advocated. `INSTALL_BASE` does not support installing modules for multiple versions of Perl or different architectures under the same directory. You should consider whether you really want that and, if you do, use the older `PREFIX` and `LIB` settings. See the ExtUtils::Makemaker documentation for more details.

Comment: 1) This won't install dependencies. 2) `INSTALL_BASE` causes multiple problems because it doesn't create `arch` directories. In this specific case, using an arch directory when appropriate will help ensure the two Perl are compatible. 3) How does this answer the OP's question at all???